# How can I organise classes in a Laravel 5 Project?

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a Task Management App. In App there is a *User* Model and there is *Project* and *Task* models.

In order for user to add a Project and related Task, all I would do at Model Level is:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function add($user_id,$task_details)
    {
        //Add Project Meta
        $this->title = "Project Title";
        $this->description "Desc"
        $this->save()

        for($t=0;$t<count($task_details);$t++) {
        //Add Task Details
        $task = new Task();
        $task->title = $task_details["title"];
        $task->description = $task_details["description"];
        $task->save();
        }
    }
}
```

It looks clumsy to me. How can I improve this in Laravel 5? How can I make my modules more atomic?

Comment: You could use a Repository pattern: https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/ (so that your project class stays small)

Comment: You might want to look into october cms, the way they added a layer over laravel for management of things makes programming these kind of things very easy, once you get the hang of it. Just a  suggestion :-)

Comment: Actually `Table Data Gateways` is what I wanted to express (http://ryantablada.com/post/i-made-a-huge-mistake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it is clumsy. You should use **Repository pattern** so that there is no such type of multiple responsibilities.
And Eloquent already has a create method like **findorCreate** or just create method.
Here is simple example for UserRepository.

```
//UserRepository
<?php namespace App\Repository\User;
use App\User;


class UserRepository{
   public $model;
   public function __construct(User $userModel) // type hinting the User Model
   {
     $this->model=$userModel;
   }
   public function create($inputs)
   { 
      return $this->model->create($inputs);
   }

}


// UserController

<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \App\Repository\User\UserRepository;
class UserController extends Controller{

   public $userRepo;

   public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository) //type hinting the userRepository Class
   {
      $this->userRepo=$userRepository;
   }

   public function getUser($id)
   {
      return $this->userRepo->model->findorfail($id);
   }
   public function getCreate()
   {
      if($this->userRepo->create(Input::all())
        return view('success');
      return Redirect->back()->withErrors();
   }
}
```

Comment: So In my case where a `user` adds a `project`. Where do I put it?

Comment: you are doing lot of stuff in your project model... you don't need to do that. Add method in user repository called **addProject($projectId)** (or whatever method name you want to give) and implement it over there. And if you are using pivot table for user project and task relationships like **belongsToMany**, then you just have to do something like this:- **$this->user->project->attach($projectId)** or **$this->user->project->sync([arrayofProjectId])**

Comment: Upvote for SRP & Repository pattern! Also, when you start adding business logic, service providers are your friend!