# constructor injection vs method injection

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, laravel-5, dependency-injection

Laravel encourages dependency injection. Since I am using laravel on my project, I figured I'll try using this approach.

I am taking advantage of Laravel's service container by [type hinting my dependencies and letting it resolve them](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers). I have four controllers. All of them extend a base class called GlobalController. I also have two models. All of them extend a base class called GlobalModel.

My first attempt is using method injection. GlobalController looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\GlobalModel;

class GlobalController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['authenticate', 'token']);
    }

    // functions that handle normal http requests and ajax requests

    }
```

One of the controllers that extends from GlobalController is called UserController. Some of its functions are:

- index - show all data
- edit - show edit form
- update - updates to database

Edit and update use [route-model-binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding).

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends GlobalController
{

    public function index(User $user)
    {
        $users = $user->all();
        return view('pages/view_users')->with('users', $users);
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        return view('pages/edit_user')->with('user', $user);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        if ($user->validate($data))
        {
            $user->update($data);
            return $this->successResponse($request, 'users', 'Successfully edited user');
        }
        return $this->failedResponse($request, $user);
    }

    // other functions

    }
```

While this is working fine, Request and User get injected many times. If I have to change a Request implementation (for example), I'll have to manually change many functions to type hint that particular Request object. Not good at all. Since they are usually called in most functions, I tried doing constructor injection.

Here is GlobalController using constructor injection:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\GlobalModel;

class GlobalController extends Controller
{
    protected $request;
    protected $model; // use polymorphism

    public function __construct(Request $request, GlobalModel $model)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->middleware(['authenticate', 'token']);
    }

    // functions that handle normal http requests and ajax requests

}
```

And here is UserController using constructor injection containing the same functions:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends GlobalController
{

    public function __construct(Request $request, User $user) // use polymorphism
    {
        parent::__construct($request, $user);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->model->all();
        return view('pages/view_users')->with('users', $users);
    }

    public function edit(int $id)
    {
        $this->model = $this->model->find($id);
        return view('pages/edit_user')->with('user', $this->model);
    }

    public function update(int $id)
    {
        $this->model = $this->model->find($id);
        $data = $this->request->all();
        if ($this->model->validate($data))
        {
            $this->model->update($data);
            return $this->successResponse('users', 'Successfully edited user');
        }
        return $this->failedResponse();
    }

    // other functions

}
```

Now, I can't put my finger on it, but I think this implementation seems not right. It became less readable. The usage of $model and $this have made the code more disgusting.

I am so confused. I understand the benefits I can get from dependency injection, but I am sure my implementations of method injection and constructor injection are extremely wrong. What implementation should I choose? Or should I choose any from these two at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely prefer the first method for Laravel Controllers. At first you don't need an injected model in every method. ( Why would you inject a user model in the index function?).

Second you cannot use the benefits of RouteModelBinding any longer and have to manually check whether a model with given $id really exists and take actions accordingly. Also you cannot use specific FormRequests like CreateUserRequest that could handle validation and authorisation. (This is an optional feature though)

Also note, that a model injected in constructor is never a 'real' model with user data. So this will just give you access to the eleoquent functions. So you could as well use User::find($id) in your code. This will always give you false.

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    dd($user->exists);
}
```

If you want to abstract things you could inject repositories in your constructor.

```
public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
{
   $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
   // then the Repository is responsible for retrieving users
   // and you are not coupled to Eloquent. If you later want, you can Read
   // users from an XML File if you need
}
```

Additional info ( a bit offtopic ): Although it is very uncommon and I have never needed to change the request class you can do this by creating a custom request class like this:

```
namespace App;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyRequest extends Request
{
   // override request methods or add your new own methods
}
```

And then in the global index.php :

```
    $response = $kernel->handle(
    // instead of Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    $request = \App\MyRequest::capture()
);
```

Comment: "Why would you inject a user model in the index function?)." - the index function gets all data to the view. I need $user to do $user->all(). Is this bad?

Comment: or just call User::all() . You don't need a specific user instance if you want to get all users. Or use a UserRepository if you feel this is better for you.

Comment: ah, you're right. I can use facades! But doesn't facades do the same thing? Do you mean to say the facade doesn't create a new User instance when calling all? I guess I just want to avoid facades as much as possible.

Comment: ultimately in every case Illuminate\Database\Eloquent::all() is called

Comment: And also Eloquent Models are no facades ;) And yes if you call User::all() no User model is instantiated. It just calls the static function all() of  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent. In fact If you call $user->all()  ALSO the static method is called. You could see that as an indicator that this is not the intended use case.

Comment: What do you do if you want to override some Eloquent model methods for testing? I sometimes override the User model to give it some specific behaviour in the test case, throw it into the service container and load it in constructors, such that the models retrieved are the overriding ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the model is being used in most of the methods, use constructor injection.
And there is nothing wrong with the usage of $model and $this. But if you still want to clean the code, consider Repository pattern (SRP). You can manage the long lines of code there.
See this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088969/how-can-i-organise-classes-in-a-laravel-5-project/32089262#32089262) - [How can I organise classes in a Laravel 5 Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088969/how-can-i-organise-classes-in-a-laravel-5-project/32089262#32089262). I hope this will help your confusion.